# Stop the main timeline from within a Class function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, stage

I need to stop the movie at the first frame using a function from a class, I know I can use stop(); or this.stop(); but how do I stop the main timeline from within a class function?

```
package {

  public class myApplication {

    public function myApplication(stageRoot:Stage) {
       stop(); // this doesn't work
       this.stop(); // this doesn't work either
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the main timeline from any display object (that is on the display list) by using the `root` keyword:

```
MovieClip(root).stop();
```

If your class is not on the display list (as appears to be your case), then you'll need to pass in a reference to something that is.  I see you are passing in a stage reference, so you could use that:

```
MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(0)).stop();
```

The main timeline (unless you've manually added something else to the stage at position 0) will be the first child of the `stage`.

So you code would then look like this:

```
public function myApplication(stageRoot:Stage) {
   MovieClip(stageRoot.getChildAt(0)).stop();
}
```

OR, if based off your comments you just pass root timeline in:

```
public function myApplication(timelineRoot:MovieClip){
    timelineRoot.stop();

    //stage can be had by doing:  timelineRoot.stage
}
```

Comment: I realized that I could pass "this" as an extra argument for the timeline but what type is this? public function myApplication(stageRoot:Stage, timelineRoot) If I put :MainTimeline or :Timeline for timelineRoot, it throws errors, without type is fine.

Comment: just pass it as `MovieClip`  -  `myApplication(timelineRoot:MovieClip)`.  You can access the stage from it:   `timelineRoot.stage`, no need for another parameter