# Is there an easy way to stop the stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to show "time is up" movie clip when the main time's over.Then goes to specific frame when 3 seconds countdown is over.I use the remove event listener,but I'll have write to code for all listeners and all levels.Is there an easy way of doing this?

```
import flash.net.SharedObject;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import Turn;
import ScoreHolder;
 
timeisup.visible = false ;
 
//This timer start when the main timer stop.
var threesecond:Timer = new Timer(3000,0);
 
////MAIN TIMER
var minute:Number = 0;
var second:Number = 15;
 
//This timer check to timer and set to what happen if time over.
var timercheck:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);
timercheck.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timercheck1);
timercheck.start();
 
function timercheck1(evt:TimerEvent):void {
if (minute <1 && second <1)
{
timer.stop();
timeisup.visible = true;
timeisup.play();
threesecond.start();
 
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, h1);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, h2);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, h3);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, h4);
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, h5);

    } 
}
 
////What gonna happen to when threesecond over
threesecond.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, zamanbittia);
 
function zamanbittia(evt:TimerEvent):void 
{
gotoAndPlay(392);       
} 
 
// Create the timer
// Checks the clock function every 1000 milisecond (1 second)
 
var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, clock);
timer.start();
 
// Function that increments the timer
function clock(evt:TimerEvent):void { 
// every time this function is checked increment second by one
second -= 1;
// If the second is 59
if(second < 0){
// The minute will be plussed with 1
minute -= 1;
//and the zero will be set to 00
second = 59;
}
```

Also I tried

```
stage.frameRate = 0.01;
```

But it's to slow and If the timer stops while moving to objects then I get error.

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you want to do.   If you want to stop all nested movie clips, then you can simply do: `stage.stopAllMovieClips();`

Comment: My buttons moving randomly on the stage I trying stop of them.Is not working.

Comment: It's unclear though how you are moving your buttons, where your buttons are in context to what you've shown and what much of your code is doing (eg all those ENTER_FRAME remove event listeners)

Answer (score 0):

stop(); in your main script
See different scenarios of implementation here [Stop the main timeline from within a Class function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30220624/stop-the-main-timeline-from-within-a-class-function)

Comment: Stop(); it's couldn't stop the moving buttons.

Comment: You have to put the frame code wherever the animation is or target it from your main frame code by doing this.whateverButton_mc.stop();